# Blazor WASM - Exclude a page depending on environment

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM application hosted with ASP.NET Core.

In the WASM client application, is it possible to exclude a page altogether depending on the environment? For example, I have some debug pages but I would only like those to be included if it's under a 'dev' or 'qa' environment.

Is it possible to do this?

I understand that it should be possible to hide the page using 'IWebAssemblyHostEnvironment', but my understanding is that it would just stop the page from rendering instead of excluding the page altogether from the application.

```cs
@inject IWebAssemblyHostEnvironment hostEnvironment

@if(hostEnvironment.IsDevelopment()){
   <p>Dev only</p>
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: IsDevelopment is a runtime environment setting - that cannot affect what you build and publish. More likely what you want is to exclude certain pages/components from being included in a Release build - is that right?

Comment: Exactly, something like conditional compilation to completely remove it from the release

Answer (score 4):

You can remove files from the project by adding a section to your `.csproj` or other relevant msbuild file in the project.

e.g. This removes a `SysDebug` component (razor file) in Release mode:

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
  <Content Remove="Pages\SysDebug.razor" />
</ItemGroup>
```